# Django) queryset filtering in view with ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset, django-urls

I've been spending hours on queryset handling of ManyToMany field type.
I want to `GET` objects(`model B`) which has ManyToMany relationship with another object(`model A`), by using `filter` on `model A`.

views.py

I get `my_user_id` from `urls.py`, which is `str`.
`id` part works fine, but...

```
class UserUserId(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    #permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer #serializer for User model

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs['my_user_id']
        return self.queryset.filter(user_id=id).user_schedules.all()
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<str:my_user_id>', views.UserUserId.as_view()),
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_schedules = models.ManyToManyField('Schedule',
            related_name='%(class)s_id')

class Schedule(models.Model):
    sched_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sched_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

It gives me following error :
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user_schedules'
I tried to resolve this issue by put `[0]` at the end of `filter()`, but It seems wrong and It doesn't work if I have to check multiple User objects.

So how can I GET `user_schedules` list of specific `User` whose `user_id` is `my_user_id`?

I'm stuck on this for hours, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: But here you want to return the related `user_schedules`? Whereas the `serializer` is a `UserSerializer`? Shouldn't the serializer then be a `ScheduleSerializer`?

Comment: Oh I think you're right. But that doesn't solve the issue. Same error comes up  about query type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you probably want to use a different serializer (something like `SchedulerSerializer`) since you suggest that you want to serialize, well, `Schedule`s.

You can obtain all `Schedule`s for a `User` with a given `user_id` with:

```
class UserUserId(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    #permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
    queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer #serializer for User model

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs['my_user_id']
        return self.queryset.filter(user__user_id=id)
```

We thus query over the `Schedule` model, and filter such that we retrieve *all* `Schedule`s for which there exists a *related* `User` with `user_id=id`.

Comment: Can I filter Schedule queryset with `user`? There's no field named `user` inside of schedule model..
It gives me this message : 
`FieldError at /user/user1
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: sched_id, sched_name` How can I match objects which has ManyToMany relationship..???

Comment: I tried `myUser = self.queryset.get(user_id=id)` and then return `myUser.user_schedules.all()`, but It gave me this error too : ```AssertionError: `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>` ```

Answer (score 2):

You want to get data for an instance, but your code is trying to get it from a queryset.

The following lines should help you out:

```
class UserUserId(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    #permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer #serializer for User model

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs['my_user_id']
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
        return list(user.user_schedules.all())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, It gave me another error : `AssertionError: Expected a Response, HttpResponse or HttpStreamingResponse to be returned from the view, but received a <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
`

Comment: I've been dealing with those two errors.. And I couldn't figure it out yet. Maybe It's because we use .all() ?

Comment: You should likely serialize this queryset.

Comment: I have changed my code, in order to convert the queryset into a list.